# Unexpected token '{'. Import call expects exactly one argument

Tags: import, token, react-native

"I am new to all of this and this is my first posted question! I'm working on react-native Android application. After building an application, It shows me an error - Unexpected token '{' in react-native, import call expects exactly one argument.
I have checked my source code many times, but I haven't got any solution related to this error. What should i do??

here is my pakage.json file-

```
 { "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.2.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.4.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^3.2.1",
    "jetifier": "^1.0.1",
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "^0.59.8",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "0.8.0",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.2.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-google-signin": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.28.0",
    "react-native-otp-inputs": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^2.14.0",
    "react-native-popup-dialog": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-razorpay": "^2.1.23",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.1",
    "react-native-webview": "^6.3.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.3.2",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^1.0.0",
    "react-navigation-transitions": "^1.0.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.4.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "jest": "24.4.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.53.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
}
```

here is the error i have after app build on my phone

https://imgur.com/lnrcso8.png

Comment: Provide error-causing code.

Answer (score 1):

While you have not provided any clear code or environment information to help us know what is causing this issue, please try [clearing the react-native cache](https://medium.com/@abhisheknalwaya/how-to-clear-react-native-cache-c435c258834e) and if that doesn't work, you may have an issue with your dependency trees in package.json.

Comment: I did clear cache, also checked the dependency tree in package.json. but still on same issue.